# regex: find integer but not float

Tags: c#, c++, regex, stl

I want a regex pattern to find any integer in the string, but not float (with decimal point as "." or ",". So for string:

abc111.222dfg333hfg44.55

it should only find:

333

I created regex pattern:

```
(?<!\\d[\\.,]|\\d)\\d+(?![\\.,]\\d+|\\d)
```

but it fails when using in C++ STL regex. It throws exception:

```
Unhandled exception at at 0x76AF4598 in xxxxxx.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::regex_error at memory location 0x00C1F218.
```

but it works nice in C# Regex class

**UPDATE:**

My Code:

```
smatch intMatch;
regex e1("(?<!\\d[\\.,]|\\d)\\d+(?![\\.,]\\d+|\\d)");
string s("111.222dfg333hfg44.55");
regex_search ( s, intMatch, e1 );
```

but it throws exception on the line:

```
regex e1("(?<!\\d[\\.,]|\\d)\\d+(?![\\.,]\\d+|\\d)");
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Both answers are correct, but for C++ STL regex Toto one works better.

Comment: The problem almost certainly lies in your code, but you haven't shown any, so it's impossible to answer.

Comment: .NET Regular Expression syntax is different to STL regular expressions.

Comment: Honestly, for a problem like what you describe, a simple "character-eater" state-machine parser would be quicker to write and easier to understand, and undoubtably faster in execution too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure for C++ STL, but many regex flavors don't support variable length negative lookbehind.

In your case you can simply do:

```
(?:^|[^.,\d])(\d+)(?:[^.,\d]|$)
```

Comment: OP's negative lookbehind is not variable length

Comment: thank you for reply, but your template does not retur what I want. For the example from my questions it find: "c111", "222d", "g333h", "g44", "55", insted of "333"

Comment: @karthikmanchala: Yes it is, it is trying to match a digit or a punctuation + a digit, so 1 or 2 character.

Comment: @user3057544: See my edit, I've added digit in character class.

Comment: @Toto - almost fine, but now it finds: "g333h", instead of "333"

Comment: @user3057544: use the group 1, add parenthesis arround the `\d+`

Comment: @Toto - the same result - "g333h"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90154/discussion-between-user3057544-and-toto).

Comment: @user3057544 this regex works if there is no cases like integer followed or preceded by `,` or `.`, like [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/lE7lE1/2)

Answer (score 1):

As there could be many differences in regex flavours used by different languages/versions/etc., I would try to handle this problem with basic regex functions, supported by most flavours, like:

```
\d+[,.]\d+|(\d+)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lE7lE1/1)

It use only alternative and group capturing, no lookarounds. The integers are captured into 1st group.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to know that inside a group of characters like in [] you should not escape metacharacters, so instead of `[\\.,]` you have to write `[.,]`. I've tried the following program and it seems to find the correct matches

```
std::string in = "abc111.222dfg333hfg44.55";

boost::regex re("(?<!(\\d[.,]|.\\d))\\d+(?![.,\\d])");

boost::sregex_iterator it(in.begin(), in.end(), re);
boost::sregex_iterator end;

for( ;it!=end; ++it)
{
    boost::smatch s = *it;
    std::cout << s[0] << std::endl;
}
```